# Scala: Create object only if it doesn't exist yet

Tags: scala, object

I'm new to Scala, and this probably a very simple question, but I'm struggling to figure out how to make an object only if one doesn't exist yet.

I would like to query a database, and find out if there's anything present, if so, store it in an object, otherwise create a new one. In Java I know that this would be something like

```
PushMessage push = null;

if(GetFromDatabase() == null) {
   push = new PushMessaage(param1, param2...);
}
else {
   push = GetFromDatabase();
}
```

But, how do I do this in Scala. When I try and do the same thing, it tells me that GetFromDatabase() doesn't conform to expected type Null. Similarly, I tried doing pattern matching and doing something like

```
val push = GetFromDatabase match {
   case Some(pushMessage) => pushMessage
   case None => new PushMessage(param1, param2...)
}
```

But, that also didn't work as it told me that

> Constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type, found: Some[A], expected: PushMessage

So, how do I do this? Any and all help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why use `Option` where you can simply do the same thing as in Java? `val m = GetFromDatabase; val push = if (m == null) { new PushMessage... } else m`.

Comment: @Victor Moroz how is it simpler than `Option(GetFromDatabase).getOrElse(new PushMessage(params))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your `GetFromDatabase` returns either `null` or `PushMessage`, so in order to pattern match correctly, you need to wrap it into `Option`:

```
val push = Option(GetFromDatabase) match {
   case Some(pushMessage) => pushMessage
   case None => new PushMessage(param1, param2...)
}
```

Or (bad style, but gives an understanding of how it works):

```
// Option(null) === None, Option(notNull) === Some(notNull):
// same as `if (x ne null) Some(x) else None
val pushMaybe: Option[PushMessage] = Option(GetFromDatabase)

val push: PushMessage = 
  if (pushMaybe.isEmpty) new PushMessage(param1, param2...)
  else pushMaybe.get
```

You can simplify it all with:

```
val push = Option(GetFromDatabase).getOrElse(new PushMessage(param1, param2...))
```

P.S. If `GetFromDatabase` isn't some external method, it's better to rewrite it as returning `Option[PushMessage]` instead of `PushMessage`, something like:

```
def getFromDatabase = {
  val rs = driver.getResulSet(query)
  if (!rs.isBeforeFirst()) None else Some(parse(rs))
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to store push to `null` if there's actually nothing there. Like to have `None => null` so that I can ask if it's empty or not?

Comment: you can use `.isEmpty`/`.nonEmpty` methods of `Option` in order to check it

Comment: Maybe it's easier to match `null` and default instead of wrapping ref value in `Option`? What's the advantage?

Comment: @Victor The code is simpler and shorter (`getOrElse`), it's basically one-liner. Besides, it's a bad-style to directly work with `null`s in scala. Even the OP's code could be refactored and someone might forget that the value is nullable, so the best way is to not expose nullable values without wrapping to `Option` at all.  `GetFromDatabase` should return `Option`

Comment: @VictorMoroz I hope it's clear that forgetting something is nullable is a risk of runtime error (`NullPointerException`), so such code wouldn't be type-safe. So wrapping to the `Option` is not only giving a simpler, but also more supportable code.

Comment: You already have `null` from `GetFromDatabase`, there is nothing you can do about it. I don't advocate for propagating it further, but doing unnecessary conversion which is only used in the next line doesn't make much sense to me. After all, such conversion cost something, you need to instantiate a new object. Add to that implicit `isInstanceOf` in the `match` instead of simple comparison.

Comment: Not to mention that I don't see much consistency in Scala's `Option(null)`. `Option(1) == Some(1)` vs `Option(null) != Some(null)`. Looks like a hack when you do `if (x == null) None else Some(x)`, but maybe it's just me.

Comment: "You already have null from GetFromDatabase" you can always wrap java API or maybe this sentence isn't right at all - see my code-sample for `ResultSet` (JDBC).  "but maybe it's just me." basically you can do research on internet, for me it looks consistent enough regarding that `null` shouldn't exist in type-safe language, that adaptor is just a compensation of JVM/Java's type-safety leaks.

Comment: I agree that it makes sense to wrap Java API, but only if you use it more than once, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little demonstration why "cool" things are not always cool. Let's see Scala generated code for two cases (I made them very simple):

```
def getMessage: String = null
val m = getMessage
val push = if (m == null) new AnyRef else m
```

=>

```
iw.this.m = iw.this.getMessage();
iw.this.push = if (iw.this.m().==(null))
  new Object()
else
  iw.this.m();
```

vs

```
def getMessage: String = null
val push = Option(getMessage) match {
   case Some(x) => x
   case None => new AnyRef
}
```

=>

```
iw.this.push = {
  case <synthetic> val x1: Option = scala.Option.apply(iw.this.getMessage());
  case6(){
    if (x1.$isInstanceOf[Some]())
      {
        <synthetic> val x2: Some = (x1.$asInstanceOf[Some](): Some);
        {
          val x: String = x2.x().$asInstanceOf[String]();
          matchEnd5(x)
        }
      }
    else
      case7()
  };
  case7(){
    if (scala.None.==(x1))
      matchEnd5(new Object())
    else
      case8()
  };
  case8(){
    matchEnd5(throw new MatchError(x1))
  };
  matchEnd5(x: Object){
    x
  }
};
```

So as long as we are not propagating `null` (and we don't) I don't see any advantages of the second option.

**UPDATE**

As requested:

```
val path = Option(m).getOrElse(new AnyRef)
```

=>

```
final <artifact> private[this] def $anonfun$1(): Object = new Object();
...
iw.this.path = scala.Option.apply($line13.iw.m()).getOrElse({
  (() => iw.this.$anonfun$1())
});
```

I wouldn't consider it much better than the second option above. `getOrElse` hides about the same logic, and we have anonymous function since `getOrElse` takes by-name argument.

In fact it's not just about saving cycles. Constructing and deconstructing `Option` object for the sake of avoiding local `null`? Or saving one line? I would totally accept it if we used `Option` for passing it further.

Comment: scala generates a lot  of boilerplate, so if you need high-performant (on low-level) language/platform maybe JVM isn't right choice at all. Could you add javap for `getOrElse` to make this comparison complete?

Comment: @dk14 Done. It's more about Occam's razor, than about cycles though :)